# Bean not found with @SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, compilation, microservices

I have a problem with microservices in JAVA. I do not understand why my code does not want to compile.

I follow a tutorial, video (in French) to create a simple project to become familiar with microservices.

I create a controller, dao and a model. When I compile the controller to access the 127.0.0.1.1port/Produits it must return me the list of the products that I defined in the code BUT at the compilation it shows me that I once have a hand:

> "Error: the method main is not found in the class

"while normally to start the project I do not need to hand because it must just tell me" Ok you can go on the 127.0.0.1/Port "(The port is defined in the application. properties and have not occupied)

Here is the architecture of my project:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIFqx.png)

Here is the code of my controller that I want to compile:

```
package com.ecommerce.microcommerce.controller;

import com.ecommerce.microcommerce.dao.ProductDao;
import com.ecommerce.microcommerce.model.Product;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductDao productDao;

    //Produits
    @GetMapping(value = "Produits")
    public List<Product> listeProduits() {
        return productDao.finAll();
    }

    //Produits/{id}
    @GetMapping(value = "Produits/{id}")
    public Product afficherUnProduit(@PathVariable int id) {
        Product product = new Product(1, new String("aspirateur"), 100);
        return product;
    }

}
```

My files from my DAO:

```
package com.ecommerce.microcommerce.dao;

import com.ecommerce.microcommerce.model.Product;
import java.util.List;

public interface ProductDao {

    public List<Product> finAll();

    public Product finById(int id);

    public Product save(Product product);

}
```

---

```
package com.ecommerce.microcommerce.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.ecommerce.microcommerce.model.Product;

@Repository 
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

    public static List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        products.add(new Product(1, new String("Ordinateur portable"), 350));
        products.add(new Product(2, new String("Aspirateur robot"), 500));
        products.add(new Product(3, new String("Table de ping pong"), 750));

    }

    @Override
    public List<Product> finAll() {
        return products;
    }
    @Override
    public Product finById(int id) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public Product save(Product product) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My files from my Model:

```
package com.ecommerce.microcommerce.model;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MicrocommerceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicrocommerceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.ecommerce.microcommerce.model;

public class Product {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int prix;

    public Product(int id, String name, int prix) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.prix = prix;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrix() {
        return prix;
    }

    public void setPrix(int prix) {
        this.prix = prix;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", prix=" + prix + "]";
    }

}
```

I saw that a lot of people had a compilation problem on other post but no answer to my problem

Thanks in advance, the code is long but very simple. I never know if I put too much or not enough. I put everything. Thank you

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Meaning: please include the error message(s) you got (as text). Dont expect us to follow that tutorial, download all the sources and try to compile ourselves (which might also lead to completely different issues than the one you are facing).

Comment: You do not read the subject. I put the error he's showing me

Comment: It isn't in the subject, but was hidden in that one large paragraph. And still, really hard to comprehend. I will undo my vote, and close request, but I still think you should spend some time looking at [mcve]...

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this gesture. I will make an effort for my next post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your `MicrocommerceApplication` (Main Class) class and other **Beans** such as `ProductDaoImpl` and `ProductController` are in different packages, Spring is unable to discover them.

> @SpringBootApplication = @Configuration + @ComponentScan + @EnableAutoConfiguration

**The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is equivalent to using  `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` with their default attributes: [...]**

The default [@ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)  is used which **searches for beans in current package only**.

If you want a custom configuration, provide your own `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan`, as appropriate.

**Solutions to your Problem:**

1. You can use the hack to move `MicrocommerceApplication` and all the other Beans **inside the same package**.
2. In place of `@SpringBootApplication` you can use:

   ```
   package com.ecommerce.microcommerce.model;

   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

   @Configuration
   @EnableAutoConfiguration
   @ComponentScan({
                    "com.ecommerce.microcommerce.controller",
                    "com.ecommerce.microcommerce.dao"
                    "com.ecommerce.microcommerce.model"})
   public class MicrocommerceApplication {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(MicrocommerceApplication.class, args);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try to move the MicrocommerceApplication class to package

> com.ecommerce.microcommerce

Another thing, default address is your localhost(127.0.0.1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just moved but I still have the same mistake. I also updated this class to fit its new folder but without success. I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement your custom runner to run the application, if you want your main class in another package, like :

```
@Component
public class ApplicationRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

        @Autowired
        private ProductController productController;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO
        }
    }
```

I hope it works !